# Change barStyle React Native based on the rendered background image

Tags: android, ios, react-native, statusbar

I can't seem to find this anywhere or I might be using the wrong keyword to search, but how do I change the barStyle on React Native (light-content/dark-content) based on the rendered background image's color

edit:

I have single screen which renders different kinds of images, what I want to achieve is how to change the barStyle based on what image currently showing on the screen. Is there even any way to do that?

case 1:
[light-background image with dark-content barStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akozZ.png)

case 2
[dark-background image with light-content barStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSFet.png)

Comment: Can you give some examples, please? Like picture what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan I uploaded two cases of what I want to get

Answer (score 0):

import statusbar and add in render method and set barStyle according to what you want.

**try this**

```
import {  StatusBar, View } from "react-native";
    render() {
       return (<View>
         <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
         .....
       </view>);
    }
```

Comment: This is what I usually do
But, please check my attachments to know what I want to achieve
There's only one screen but I want to change the barStyle by what image's color currently showing

Answer (score 0):

Setting `StatusBar` as `transluent` along with `backgroundColor` as `transparent`, you can achieve this which is as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from "react-native";

const image1 = { uri: "https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero.jpg" };
const image2 = { uri: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png" };

export default class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);
    StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("transparent");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={image1} style={styles.image}>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover"
  }
});
```

1. If you use `image1`, your output will be like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJXCV.jpg).
2. If you use `image2`, your output will be like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1LqT.jpg).

Comment: This seems do. But what if my image actually have white as the background color?
If that's the case, the barStyle should be changed to dark-content, am I right?
How do I automate this since the images itself is dynamically changes

Comment: I think you're changing your image, it will set the image on top of the status bar. So if you change your image dynamically, it will do the same. Your pictures are doing the same, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. But currently we are not changing the barStyle. I use this code and change my image to the one with white background and the status bar seems invisible because the barStyle props still light-content

Comment: Like, you want the statusBar's color same as your image's color. That's why no need to change the barStyle, you can do in this way. Just use same style for every image.

Comment: My focus point is not the statusBar's background color but the text's color. Because currently the statusbar only either light-content or dark-content.